# Error in mutual information when using a subset

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information, subset

I want to compute the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) for ~4000 different pairs, where each pair contains two vectors. Each of these vectors hold 100000 observations, making this computation very computationally intensive when using [Minepy](http://minepy.sourceforge.net/). Therefore, it would be nice to just use a sample of these observations to compute the mutual information. How much would it affect the value of mutual information if I only took a random sample of 1000 observations for each of the vectors and used that instead?

Comment: How do you define the mutual information metric between two "vectors of 100.000 observations" ? This question is extremely ambiguous right now

Comment: I've deleted the use of the word `metric` as I meant the standard definition of mutual information.

Comment: Even without "metric" you still are in trouble. There's no such thing as mutual information between vectors. Mutual information is defined between probability distributions

Comment: Well.. I'm analyzing user behavior, where each observation is a user. The total number of users is ~2 mio, whereas I'm analyzing 100.000 randomly drawn users. Each feature in the data is split into a separate vector. In this way I see each vector as 100.000 observations drawn from the distribution of that feature. Does that still seem problematic?

Comment: If I give you vectors V1, V2, exactly what are the exact operations that compute d(V1,V2) ?

Comment: I use minepy, which performs binning to estimate p(x), p(y) and p(x,y). If you search on Google there's lot of materials on comparing vectors with MI for engineering applications. But I'm of course interested in hearing if you disagree with that :)

Comment: I don't like using mutual information exactly because it's very hard to compute from a dataset. Binning has issues but it's a simple computation at least. When you reduce the size of your data-set, you will get into issues of the estimation of the binned probability being poor, and so your estimate of the mutual information might have increased error here.

Comment: What are your thoughts then on the answer by Florin Schimbinschi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the formula:

[image]

I(X,Y) measures the shared information between X and Y.
p(x,y) is the *joint* probability density function.
The marginal p(x) describes the relative likelihood for the random variable X to take on a particular value x (also, a probability density function).

> The question is actually whether the random sample is representative of the population marginal distribution.

Each time you take a random sample for one vector you have a different p(x) for vector x. If your sample is large enough and you're lucky, then this should be a good approximation and you're done. 
Now, let's say you want to be more confident about this approximation.
You repeat several times and you get multiple estimations of this distribution. Average these and you have a good approximation of the population distribution, which usually turns out to be a gaussian.

This is called the [**Central limit theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Applications_and_examples) which states that if a *sufficiently large number* of samples is taken from a population (given some conditions), then the distribution will be normal.

> **TL/DR**: You need to randomly sample without replacement multiple times. In your case, this means you randomly select rows from your dataset, let's say S=1000 rows / observations as in your example and repeat this N=10 times. Average the results and you should get an accurate approximation. Adjust S and N according to your computational constraints.

"[Dice sum central limit theorem](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dice_sum_central_limit_theorem.svg#/media/File:Dice_sum_central_limit_theorem.svg)" by [Cmglee](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Cmglee)
shows how the approximation gets better as n increases.

[image]

Comment: "The question is actually whether the random sample is representative of the population marginal distribution." Good point. However, what about p(x,y)? How do we know whether the sample is representative of the joint probability density function?

Comment: The joint pdf is dependent on the marginals. If the marginals are representative for _both_ vectors, then this will be reflected in the joint pdf as well. 
I assumed that your observations are correlated, that is why the same rows of observations should be selected for both / all vectors. The procedure is: 1) generate S random integers from 1 to 100,000. 2) Select all rows with those integers for all vectors. 3) Compute MI 4) Repeat process N times.

If the data is not correlated, (e.g. X(1) has no dependency on Y(1) ) then you can drop the constraint and sample independently for each vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can cope with the running time not by reducing your dataset size but by changing the way you do the computation.

Now you have ~4,000 pairs and you go over 100K samples for each pair , costing ~4*10^9 operations.

Instead, you can do the following:
I assume that you are checking all pairs of variables so the number of variables you have is 
n*(n-1)/2 = ~ 4,000
n ~ 100

Aggregate the samples based on all the features.
Using SQL you can do it by
select f1,f2,....fn, count(*)
from samples
group by f1,f2,....fn

That will cost you a single scan of the 100K samples.
The computation of the 4,000 pairs will cost you the size of the 4,000*|aggregated dataset|

If you have 100 (binary) variables, the size of the aggregated dataset might reach 2^100 ~10^30 >> 10^5 = 100K samples.
However, a combination not supported by any samples wont be in the aggregated dataset so the size of the aggregated dataset is at most as the size of the original one.

It is very likely that the size of the aggregated dataset will be way smaller than the original one.
If it not so it might be due to few variable causing such a spread. These are usually few variables of high entropy. You can remove the from the current list of variables and do the computation on the aggregated dataset for the rest. Then you can compute the mutual information of the high entropy variable in the direct method

You can also approximate the mutual information by removing all combination of low support (in SQL, write something like having count(*) > 10).

I would have try to avoid reducing the sample size.
You want to estimate the mutual information of 4,000 pairs with 100K samples.
More than that, computing MI involves division and log which are sensitive to estimation errors. Hence, you are likely to get some bad estimations even when using all your data.

Assuming that you are mostly interested in pair of high MI, keep a validation set to to verify these pair. It seems the moving samples from the original set to the validation is a zero sum game. However, since you would like to verify much fewer pair you will get a better estimation of the pair the you are interested in.

Another way to validated you results is by using transitivity. In case the you have a high mutual information between A and B and also both A and be have high mutual information with other variables, this is a good indicator of a true connection.